# MySQL Workbench query tabs

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying MySQL Workbench 6.0 and when I execute a query the results are displayed with a tab called "Result 1". When I fire another query the same tab is reused, now named "Results 2".

I found no way to open a new results tab (not *query* tab). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench always closes all existing resultset tabs when it executes the content in a specific tab. If you have several queries in your editor and execute all of them (and they return a result set) then a new resultset tab is created for each returned set.

If you want a specific resultset tab to stay while running other queries open it in a separate editor tab.

Comment: Is there a way to set name to the result tab in the query itself? Like automatically renaming default "Result 1" to "Students data"?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have run a query in MySQL Workbench, you can right-click and pin - and rename - the query results. The next query in the same query tab which you run, will open a new results tab, allowing you to switch between both results (multiple if you pin further result tabs) and compare results without having to re-run each query again.

Answer (score 0):

nothing to worry about. this is how it works. just counting results. if you make 2 select statements they will be in different results tabs, not like in mssql man. studio in 1.

select * from tableA -> tab tableA 1
select * from tableB -> tab tableB 1